# (java) Listen to websocket messages with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, websocket, htmlunit

I am trying to listen to websocket messages on a particular page.

It seems like HtmlUnit has support for WebSockets, but I can't find any documentation/tutorial or even an answer to: "*is it possible to intercept websocket data with htmlUnit*"?

What I already tried:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {

    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("url");
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

I get an INFO message about the websocket connection and this error:

```
INFO: Opening transport: xhr-streaming  url:https://stream71.forexpros.com:443/echo/340/3exyl8ko  RTO:357
Mar 23, 2017 5:40:07 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection downloadContent
WARNING: Connection was closed while reading from stream.
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now, `WebSocket` is supported only from the the JavaScript side by this [class](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/htmlunit/src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/javascript/host/WebSocket.java), and there is no API from HtmlUnit to control it.

The current implementation is basic, I will see if there is a way to intercept the traffic from [Jetty Websocket client](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-websocket-client-api.html), it can be added to the public API.

**Update:**

WebClient now has `getInternals().addListener()`. Once the listener.`created(WebSocket)` is called, you should invoke `webSocket.setWebSocketListener()` with the `WebSocketListener`.

Test case is [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/13880/tree/trunk/htmlunit/src/test/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/javascript/host/WebSocketTest.java#l484).

This feature is included in the [latest build](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts).

Comment: thank you, that's what I concluded too. It would really be great to have this support though.

Comment: I guess there is a way, but the question is how best to add it. Stay tuned :)